# C# Generics - Determine generic type from consuming generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Long story: I'm working on a system that will have `Tasks` and `Handlers`.  Tasks will be sent from disparate parts of the system to the Handlers, where they will eventually return a value.

We've got a system in-place that is loosely-typed and has turned into something of a gnarled mess (the problem is significantly amplified by the fact that the task-initiators are often coming from third-party components that are essentially plug-ins).

I've been thinking of ways to implement the same in a strongly-typed fashion--and might just be taking this to the point of obsurdity--but am close to what I'd *like*.  The problem is some syntax.

Here's what I've got (generic names expanded for clarity):

```
interface ITask<ReturnType> { }

interface ITaskHandler<TaskType, TaskReturnType> where TaskType : ITask<TaskReturnType>
{
    TaskReturnType PerformTask(TaskType task);
}
```

As you can see, `ITask` is generic, and the declared generic parameter for `ITask` is the return-type for `ITaskHandler<ITask>`.  This means that each `TaskHandler` is contractually bound to return the type specified by its `ITask`.

The big downside that declaring TaskHandlers leads to some fairly ugly Signatures...

```
class SpecificTask : ITask<Dictionary<Type,Delegate>>
{
}

class SpecificHandler : ITaskHandler<SpecificTask, Dictionary<Type, Delegate>>
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Delegate> PerformTask(SpecificTask task)
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
    }
}
```

My question is: since `SpecificTask` has already provided it's ReturnType as a generic parameter, can `SpecificHandler`'s signature be shortened to something more like:

```
interface ITaskHandler<TaskType> where TaskType : ITask
{
    // pulling TaskReturnType out of thin air...
    TaskReturnType PerformTask(TaskType task);
}

class SpecificHandler : ITaskHandler<SpecificTask>
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Delegate> PerformTask(SpecificTask task)
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();
    }
}
```

...and if so, how would I declare the return type of `PerformTask` when the type is contained within `SpecificTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do what you want to do and retain static type checking.  All of the generic type parameters must be delared in order for the compiler to be able to statically know what goes where.

You could do this with reflection but that would completely undermine the purpose of generics in the first place.

Comment: Afraid that might be the case...  was hoping that it might just be some syntax I wasn't aware of