# Extract Generic Type From Enclosing Generic

Tags: c#, generics, types

I want something like this:

```
class Foo<T>{...}

class Boo<T>{

   Queue<T> stuff = new Queue<T>();

   public void Boo(Foo<T>){...};
}

...

//Extract the generic type - string - to define the type
//of MyBoo.
var MyBoo = new Boo(new Foo<string>());
```

I get the error "generic type 'Boo' requires '1' type arguments.  Ya, I fixed the problem by stating the template type explicitly, but I'd like to know if there was/is a way to extract that type implicitly, rather than having to state it explicitly.

This other [post may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489112/c-generics-determine-generic-type-from-consuming-generic-method), but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should be "Bar" not "Boo".

Comment: @siride is it really important?

Comment: @Andrey: no, so that's why I left it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it implicitly directly with the constructor of a generic type, but you could from a generic *method*, e.g. in a non-generic class:

```
public static class Boo
{
    public Boo<T> Create<T>(Foo<T> foo)
    {
        return new Boo<T>(foo);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
// myBoo will be inferred to be of type Boo<string>
var myBoo = Boo.Create(new Foo<string>());
```

Of course, it doesn't *have* to be another class called `Boo` - it could be something completely different, and it could be an instance method of something else:

```
var factory = new BooFactory();
var myBoo = factory.Create(new Foo<string>());
```

The important point is that it's a generic *method* - type arguments can be inferred for generic methods, but not for generic types.

Answer (score 3):

Type inference works only with methods. So if you have generic method and it is clear how to substitute generic parameter it will be substituted by compiler. For `new` operator it doesn't work so consider creating factory method like `Create` that will produce instances of `Boo`. Otherwise impossible.