# How to introduce a generic type into a class?

Tags: c#, generics, automated-refactoring

I need to change my C# code by extracting a generic type parameter from an existing C# class:

Let's say, the class is named *Foo* and the type *Bar*.

- The class will now be *Foo*`<T>`;
- all occurrences of *Bar* within the definition of *Foo* are replaced by `T`;
- all occurrences of *Foo* anywhere in my code base are replaced by *Foo*`<`*Bar*`>`.

Which existing tool can do this for me, or lets me do this easily?
Thus far I'm using regular expression search-and-replace, which gets most of the job done, but it's easy to make stupid mistakes that way.

(BTW: if you know a better name for this refactoring than 'extracting a type', let me know, so I know what to search for ...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369364/extract-generic-type-from-enclosing-generic

Comment: @Freelancer, this other question is completely unrelated...

Comment: @Freelancer: That question is related, but it is about how to make C# code do something; mine is about how to change a body of C# code.

Comment: What are you trying to get as output? A new assembly?

Comment: You should be able to "automate" the first two points by changing `class Foo` to `class Foo<Bar>` and then doing an automatic rename of `Bar` to `T`. (This should reduce your workload a bit if you can't find an all-in-one solution.)

Comment: @reinierpost ohh, i posted it if you can get help through it in any way. Sorry if its unrelated.

Comment: @Freelancer, Alex Filipovici : reworded the first sentence.

Comment: .@Rawling: I need real automation because I'll need to repeat this process quite a few times ...

Comment: do you use resharper - if so, i believe this is what you are looking for http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_Type.html

Comment: @Krishna: no, it's not.

Comment: How would you handle the `Bar` initialization, i.e.`public Foo(){MyProperty = new Bar();}`?

Comment: @Alex Filipovici: I'm happy to see an error message in the result there, or an option to have `where T : new()` added.

Comment: Do you have a class definition per file? Actually, could you post some code samples for your scenario?

Comment: @Alex Filipovici: It varies. Some of the files contain 19 interfaces and classes, including private classes.

Answer (score 2):

I just found an existing Resharper plugin that does indeed contain such a refactoring:  The [Resharper Powertoys](http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/)!

Comment: It is a collection of plugins. I haven't found any that does this. Which one is it?

Comment: It's actually the MakeMethodGeneric powertoy (so there will be a little tidying-up to make the whole class generic).

Comment: Oh, but you can get the source control from Codeplex and have a go at modifying it to do a whole class (haven't looked at the code, so not sure how brave you would have to be to do this).

Comment: I've installed it, but I can't figure out how to make its interface (whatever it is) appear on my test class. I'm [looking at the code](http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/MakeMethodGeneric/MakeMethodGenericWorkflow.cs) but it's not clear how to read it - e.g. apparently it's not enabled on methods that are ICompiledElement but what does that mean?

Comment: Well, I couldn't figure it out quickly enough so I used a Perl script this time. But I'll look into Resharper plugins in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This refactoring should be named "Introduce generic parameter", but I am not sure if any tool does that.
You can write a visitor using `NRefactory` to rewrite the code, but it will not by default give you a great resolution of all referencing places.

Maybe try writing a ReSharper plugin?

Comment: That is what I'm thinking of, but my present project doesn't really allow for such discursions.